# Backbone-forms.js - can i configure a textfield inside the script or have it to be done with jQuery after rendering it?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-forms

hi i got this form in my script, 
can i parse option values like height and width inside the script, 
or have i to style it with jQuery after rendering through that script?

```
var form1 = new Backbone.Form({
    schema: {
        country: { type: 'Select', options: ['UK', 'USA'] },
        city: { type: 'Select', options: cities.UK },
        message: { type: 'Text'}
    }
}).render();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `fieldAttrs` property to set any attributes to the element:

```
country: { 
  type: 'Select', 
  options: ['UK', 'USA'], 
  fieldAttrs: { style: "width: 400px; height: 30px;" } 
}
```

Alternatively you can provide a CSS class using the `fieldClass` property, and apply CSS rules using regular stylesheets:

```
country: { 
  type: 'Select', 
  options: ['UK', 'USA'], 
  fieldClass: 'country-select'
}
```

All the available schema attributes are [documented here](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms#main-attributes).

Comment: what I observe is as follows: `<div class="form_float_left" placeholder="hello">
<label for="c1_firstname"></label>
<div><span data-editor="">
<input id="c1_firstname" type="text" name="firstname">
</span>
<div data-error=""></div>
<div></div>
</div>
</div>`.  So all the attributes are added to the div but not to the input elements. So if I want to add "placeholder" attribute to the input then fieldattr does not work....do you have any idea how to do that ?